# What would a reptile with Facial and Speech muscles look like?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I have been wondering about how humans require facial muscles in order to be able to produce speech, mammals also have these facial muscles that could allow them to speak if they had the brain power to produce speech.

Here is an image from the internet of a wolf skull and a human skull, along with another one that contains facial muscles:

[image: Human Skull] [image: Human Facial Muscles]

[image: Dog Skull] [image: Dog Facial Muscles]

Reptiles however lack any facial muscles and therefore cannot move their face in any way, but I am wondering, what would the physical skull alterations be in order to have a carnivorous reptile with facial muscles sufficient enough that it could speak, and what would the reptile look like with facial muscles? How well would it be able to speak at this point?

[image: Skull of Lace Monitor]
[image: Lace Monitor Lizard]

Comment: I was always under the impression that facial muscles don't exactly do anything for speech. I always thought it was via the throat and tongue. The reason being is because there is thing called a ventriloquist who talks without moving their mouth or face for that matter.

Comment: To use the Sandbox you should post your question as an answer to the Sandbox post.

Comment: This should be posted as an answer to the Sandbox question. I'm closing this question as a duplicate of that; please repost your question as an answer to the sandbox question. (Yes, the sandbox is an exception to the rule that questions should not be posted as answers.) Also indicate which tags you have in mind to use. I hope you get some good answers!